# Android music player as a Service and show the title track,album image on UI

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I tried to write the music player code in android.I want to show the current title of the song,artist and album image.
    The Activity is:
    package com.example.getmusic;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import com.example.getmusic.PlayMusicService.LocalBinder;




import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class GetMusic extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
      static Handler seekhandler=new Handler();
      boolean isServiceConnected=false;
      PlayMusicService playServ;
     static  TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    Button previous,next;static ImageView img;static GestureDetector gDetector;
    int pausePressed=1;static SeekBar sb;

    int currentIndex=0;Cursor cursor;GenericSongClass GSC;
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;static int posofaudiotrack;
    private ServiceConnection conn=new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isServiceConnected=false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LocalBinder binder=(LocalBinder)service;
    playServ=binder.getService();
    isServiceConnected=true;

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_music);
        gDetector= new GestureDetector(this);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        getSongs();

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        try{
        Intent serv = new Intent(this,PlayMusicService.class);

            bindService(serv, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        System.out.println("in try calling service");
        startService(serv);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is"+e);
        }
        System.out.println("after binding");
        /* 
        try {
            playSong(0);


    }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception is"+e);
    }*/
         //PlayMusic p=new PlayMusic();
        // p.execute();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
         if (isServiceConnected) {
                unbindService(conn);
                isServiceConnected = false;
            }
    }


    public static void mediaPlayerPause()
    {

        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        {

            mediaPlayer.pause();
            posofaudiotrack=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

    }
    public void mediaPlayerResume()
    {

        if(mediaPlayer!=null&&!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    public class PlayMusic  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getSongs();
            return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public static ArrayList<GenericSongClass> songs = null;

    public void getSongs() {        

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in BindAllSongs()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
            final String[] projection = new String[] {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,

                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
                    };
                    final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE
                            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

                    try {

                        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;


                       cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
                     /*  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                       String s=cursor.getString(column_index);*/
                      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "path is"+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // System.out.println("path is"+s);


                       if (null == cursor) {
                            Log.e("error","cursor is null");
                        // If the Cursor is empty, the provider found no matches
                        } else if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {

                            Log.i("info","cursor count<1");
                        } else {



                            songs = new ArrayList<GenericSongClass>(cursor.getCount());
                            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                            int colIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                            String path = cursor.getString(colIndex);
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PATH IS"+path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("PATH IS"+path);
                            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                                GSC = new GenericSongClass();
                                GSC.songTitle = cursor.getString(0);
                                GSC.songArtist = cursor.getString(1);   
                                GSC.songData = cursor.getString(2);
                                GSC.songComposer=cursor.getString(3);
                                GSC.title=cursor.getString(4);
                                GSC.album=cursor.getString(5);

                                songs.add(GSC);
                                cursor.moveToNext();

                            }


                         //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "songs first is"+songs.get(0).songTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "songs length is"+songs.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                     Log.e("I", "Media player has been loaded to memory !");
                                }
                            });
                            /*for(int i=0;i<songs.size();i++){
                                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                                String p=songs.get(i).songData;
                                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);*/


                        }
                    }
                        catch (Exception ex) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Log.i("ex is",ex.toString());
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            cursor.close();
                        }}
                    }



    protected void getPreviousSong()
    {

        if(currentIndex==0)
            currentIndex=songs.size()-1;
        else{
            currentIndex=currentIndex-1;
            }
        playSong(currentIndex);
    }
    protected void getNextSong() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(currentIndex == songs.size()-1){
            currentIndex=0;

        }
        else
        {
            currentIndex=currentIndex+1;


        }
        playSong(currentIndex);
    }
    private void playSong(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            String p=songs.get(index).songData;
        System.out.println("Song title is"+songs.get(1).songTitle+"artist"+songs.get(1).songArtist+"composer is"+songs.get(1).songComposer.valueOf(0)+"title is"+songs.get(1).title);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      tv1.setText(songs.get(index).title);
      tv2.setText(songs.get(index).album);
      tv3.setText(songs.get(index).songArtist);
     // tv3.append(songs.get(index).album);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(p);
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        byte[] rawArt;
        Bitmap art = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();
      mmr.setDataSource(p);

        rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();



        if (null != rawArt) 
            art = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
        img.setImageBitmap(art);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("exc","exception is"+e.toString());
            System.out.println("exception is"+e.toString());
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepate exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepate exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("exception is"+e.toString());
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
        sb.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekUpdation();
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            seekhandler.removeCallbacks(run);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            seekhandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                seekhandler.removeCallbacks(run);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pausePressed=1;
                playServ.getNextSong();

            }
        });

                    }



     Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekUpdation();
            }
        };


        public void seekUpdation() {

            sb.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            seekhandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
        }
    public class GenericSongClass {

            String songTitle = "";
            String songArtist = "";
            String songData = "";
            String songComposer="";
            String title="";
            String album="";
            String isChecked = "false";
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get_music, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        pausePressed=1;//int x=playServ.getCurrentIndex();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX())
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "chanegd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(playServ!=null){

            /*  if(x==0)
                    x=songs.size()-1;
                else{
                    x=currentIndex-1;
                    }
                  tv1.setText(songs.get(x).title);
                  tv2.setText(songs.get(x).album);
                  tv3.setText(songs.get(x).songArtist);
                 tv3.append(songs.get(x).album);*/

            playServ.getPreviousSong();}
            else
                System.out.println("ms null");
        }
        else if(start.getRawX()>finish.getRawX())
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changed on other", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("onFLing","in onFling");
            if(playServ!=null){
                /*
                if(x == songs.size()-1){
                    x=0;

                }
                else
                {
                    x=x+1;


                }
                  tv1.setText(songs.get(x).title);
                  tv2.setText(songs.get(x).album);
                  tv3.setText(songs.get(x).songArtist);
                 tv3.append(songs.get(x).album);*/
            playServ.getNextSong();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("ms null");
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("PAUSEPRESSED"+pausePressed);
        if(pausePressed==1){
            pausePressed=0;
            playServ.mediaPlayerPause();
        }else if(pausePressed==0){
            pausePressed=1;


                //mediaPlayer.seekTo(posofaudiotrack);
                playServ.mediaPlayerResume();


        }
        return true;
    }

}
and the Service is:
package com.example.getmusic;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.getmusic.GetMusic.GenericSongClass;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class PlayMusicService extends Service{
    MediaPlayer mp;int currentIndex=0;
    ArrayList<GenericSongClass> songs=GetMusic.songs;int pausePressed=1;
    IBinder servbind=new LocalBinder();
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
        PlayMusicService getService()
        {
            return PlayMusicService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return servbind;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("in onPrepared");
            }
        });
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pausePressed=1;
                getNextSong();
            }
        });
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try{
      System.out.println("in try");
      playSong(0);
 }
 catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("in catch and exception is "+e.getMessage());
 }

    }

    public void playSong(int index){

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.out.println("in playsong");
            mp.reset();
            String p=songs.get(index).songData;
        System.out.println("Song title is"+songs.get(1).songTitle+"artist"+songs.get(1).songArtist+"composer is"+songs.get(1).songComposer.valueOf(0)+"title is"+songs.get(1).title);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     GetMusic.tv1.setText(songs.get(index).title);
GetMusic.tv2.setText(songs.get(index).album);
    GetMusic.tv3.setText(songs.get(index).songArtist);
    GetMusic.tv3.append(songs.get(index).album);
        mp.setDataSource(p);
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        byte[] rawArt;
        Bitmap art = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();
      mmr.setDataSource(p);

        rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();



        if (null != rawArt) 
            art = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
    GetMusic.img.setImageBitmap(art);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("exc","exception is"+e.toString());
            System.out.println("exception is"+e.toString());
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepate exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepate exception is"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("exception is"+e.toString());
        }

        mp.start();
        GetMusic.sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        seekUpdation();
GetMusic.sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GetMusic.seekhandler.removeCallbacks(run);
            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            GetMusic.seekhandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GetMusic.seekhandler.removeCallbacks(run);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



    }
     Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekUpdation();
            }
        };
     public void seekUpdation() {

            GetMusic.sb.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            GetMusic.seekhandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
        }
    public int getCurrentIndex(){
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public void mediaPlayerPause()
    {

        if(mp!=null)
        {

            mp.pause();
            //pos=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

    }
    public void mediaPlayerResume()
    {

        if(mp!=null&&!mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            mp.start();
        }
    }
    public void getPreviousSong()
    {

        if(currentIndex==0)
            currentIndex=songs.size()-1;
        else{
            currentIndex=currentIndex-1;
            }
        playSong(currentIndex);
    }
    public void getNextSong() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(currentIndex == songs.size()-1){
            currentIndex=0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentIndex=currentIndex+1;


        }
        playSong(currentIndex);
    }


    @Override   
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {   
        mp.start(); 

        return 0;

    }

    @Override   
    public void onDestroy() 
    {   
        mp.release();       
        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

The issue is it's playing good sometimes and sometimes it's stopping when we press back button or swiping other apps on home screen.I want to show the title track,image on UI.But with this code it's showing wrong images for some songs and for some it's even not showing the image even if the image exists.And after back screen pressed and so when we use other apps and get back to this It's showing simply TextView and normal android image.Is recreation of activity needed?Can we call Activity method from Service?How to solve the issues?Please help me.

Comment: Use Asynctask() and run your main code in the background. If not anything else, it will at least not stop playing unexpectedly.

Comment: Asynctask() only runs in the app right?But without using Service how can we get the music playing.

Answer (score 0):

You need background music service and communicate with Activity with message or bond activity to service, not call Activity method from service, that will cause cross process problem.

I actually opensource a Music Player with Background service, Lyric, from a business project I have wrote, you check this out:https://github.com/Wangchao0721/MusicPlayer

But I haven't got time to fill Readme for it, just check MediaPlayerActivity.java in activity package, you gonna know how to use this.

Comment: Hi I saw that but my code is stopping unexpectedly sometimes.And the image is not properly loading for some songs.What would be the reason for this?